# Integration between kafka and drools

Tags: apache-kafka, drools, rule-engine

I'm designing a system that needs:

- to consume events published using kafka,
- to apply on them some rules using a rule based engine
- to publish on kafka some events when the rules are matched.

To do a simple example (the real use cases are more complex): the system receives events from a temperature sensor, it uses drools to apply some rules on these events - i.e., a decision table with thresholds - and then it sends a suggestion on kafka, indicating "close the window", when the temperature goes beyond the threshold.

For what I have understood, reading the Drools documentation, currently my idea for developing this application is the following:

- Develop a Drools project inserting the rules to be applied using .drl.
- Configure Drools to work in Stream mode.
- Insert in the application also a kafka consumer, which consumes the events pubblished and then insert in drools a new event, every time it is received from kafka.
- Insert in the application a rules listener that is called every time a rule is executed.
- Publish an event on kafka every time the listener receives the events.

Is this a right way to proceed or is there another "standard" way to do this integration between kafka and drools?

Comment: Kafka Streams can do much of this on its own. Drools might be too much unless you already have it installed. If so, you might want to look at [Apache Camel](https://docs.drools.org/7.69.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_ch.camel) integration between it and Kafka.

Comment: Having used all three technologies -- though Drools most extensively and Camel only a very long time ago -- I agree with OneCricketeer's suggestion. Drools is probably overkill/unnecessary, and Camel is quite adept at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using Quarkus, Camel and Kogito applying very similar blueprint and solution as demonstrated in:

- this blog post: https://blog.kie.org/2022/03/content-based-routing-with-quarkus-and-kogito.html
- this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXyKM-xds2M
- this demo: https://github.com/tarilabs/quarkus-content-based-routing

The difference to compared to your use case, specifically:

> To do a simple example (the real use cases are more complex): the system receives events from a temperature sensor, it uses drools to apply some rules on these events - i.e., ***a decision table with thresholds*** - and then it sends a suggestion on kafka, indicating "close the window", when the temperature goes beyond the threshold.

(emphasis mine) is that the resources above are using DMN for a decision table, but you might as well implement the same with Drools' DRL.